# Piwik with PHP Query

Tags: php, matomo

Since I installed piwik the last time - the PHP query seams to have changed. I don't wont to use Javascript or an Image.

The Last Time my code was

```
<?php
  require_once "piwik/PiwikTracker.php";

  $t = new PiwikTracker( $idSite = 1, 'http://example.com/piwik/');
  $t->setTokenAuth( 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' );
  $t->setIp( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );
  $t->doTrackPageView(get_page_clean_title(false)." &mdash; ". get_site_name(false));
?>
```

This don't work with the new PiwikTracker.php. I tried to find out how to do it and ended with this code which don't work...

Since I have it in the head of the PHP File - the site don't load.

```
<?php
  define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 

  require_once(__ROOT__.'/piwik/PiwikTracker.php'); 

  $title = get_page_clean_title(false)." &mdash; ". get_site_name(false);
  PiwikTracker::$URL = 'http://example.com/piwik/';
  $piwikTracker = new PiwikTracker( $idSite = {2} );
  $piwikTracker->doTrackPageView($title);
?>
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I don't get any errors - they are all blocked by my hosting provider... is there a way i can dump errors to file?

Comment: which hosting are you using? Ask them to open your PHP Errors to be visible on your page

Answer (score 0):

Check if `PiwikTracker.php` exists in given directory. As far as I remember, the PHP tracking library is now loaded via submodules and the location may have changed.

Comment: I got the `PiwikTracker.php` from github and added it to my Piwik installation.